# How to share an object between multiple test suites in Jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I need to share an object (db connection pool) between multiple test suites in Jest.
I have read about [`globalSetup`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#globalsetup-string) and it seems to be the right place to initialize this object, but how can I pass that object from `globalSetup` context to each test suite context?

Comment: From the link you sent: "Any global variables that are defined through globalSetup can only be read in globalTeardown. You cannot retrieve globals defined here in your test suites."

Comment: you can also write code in the global before files hook, like this in package,json: "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/test/setup_files.js"]. but I never got that to work.

Answer (score 6):

I'm dealing with a very similar issue, although in my case I was trying to share a single DB container (I'm using [dockerode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dockerode)) that I spin up once before all tests and remove after to conserve the overhead of spinning a container for each suite.

Unfortunately for us, after going over *a lot* of documentation and [Github](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7601#issuecomment-461238200) [issues](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7184#issuecomment-491721218) my conclusion is that this is [by design](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6007#issuecomment-381743011) since Jest's philosophy is to [run tests sandboxed](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8010#issuecomment-474001093) and under that restriction, I totally get why they [choose](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7184#issuecomment-492122367) not to support this.

Specifically, for my use case I ended up spinning a container in a `globalSetup` script, tagging it with some unique identifier for the current test run (say, timestamp) and removing it at the end with a `globalTeardown` (that works since global steps can share state between them).

This looks roughly like:

```
const options: ContainerCreateOptions = {
Image: POSTGRES_IMAGE,
Tty: false,
HostConfig: {
    AutoRemove: true,
    PortBindings: {'5432/tcp': [{HostPort: `${randomPort}/tcp`}]}
},
Env: [`POSTGRES_DB=${this.env['DB_NAME']}`,
    `POSTGRES_USER=${this.env['DB_USERNAME']}`,
    `POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${this.env['DB_PASSWORD']}`]
};
options.Labels = { testContainer: `${CURRENT_TEST_TIMESTAMP}`};
let container = await this.docker.createContainer(options);
await container.start();
```

where `this.env` in my case is a `.env` file I preload based on the test.

To get the container port/ip (or whatever else I'm interested in) for my tests I use a [custom envrironment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) that my DB-requiring tests use to expose the relevant information on a `global` variable (reminder: you can only put primitives and objects on global, not instances).

In your case, the requirement to pass a connection pool between suites is probably just not suited for jest since it will never let you pass around an instance between different suites (at least that's my understanding based on all of the links I shared).  You can, however, try either:

- Put all tests that need the same connection pool into a single suite/file (not great but would answer your needs)
- Do something similar to what I suggested (setup DB once in global, construct connection pool in custom env and then at least each suite gets its own pool) that way you have a lot of code reuse for setup which is nice.  Something similar is discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6408#issuecomment-395408853).

Miscalenous: I stumbled across [testdeck](https://testdeck.org/pages/guide/inheritance) which might answer your needs as well (setup an abstract test class with your connection pool and inherit it in all required tests) - I didn't try it so I don't know how it will behave with Jest, but when I was writing in Java that's how we used to achieve similar functionality with `TestNG`

Answer (score 0):

In each test file you can define a function to load the necessary data or to mock the data. User the beforeEach() function for this. [Documentation example here!](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeeachfn-timeout)

Comment: I need to initialize an object once per *all* test suites (as I said - this is integration test environment, and I need to load the express app and initialize a DB connection pool), so `beforeEach()`, which is called before each test, and so `beforeAll()`, which is called before each test suite, do not fit that need